# Limit of $\frac{2\sin^2 x}{x^3 \sin(1/x)}$ as $x\to0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Suppose $$f(x) = \frac{2\sin^2 x}{x^3 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}}$$ Now find $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$$

My try :  $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 2(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x})^2 \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x \sin{\frac{1}{x}}}  = 2 \times  \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x \sin{\frac{1}{x}}} $

And I'm stuck here and I have no idea .

Comment: For real $y,|\sin y|\le1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Okay , How we can use it ?

Comment: @S.H.W Are you okay with result.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Please see my comment.

Comment: Limit does not exist as the denominator vanishes in neighborhood of $0$. If you are willing to adopt a relaxed definition of limit to consider only points of domain of $f$ then also you can note that the function oscillates infinitely as $x\to 0$. Thus the limit does not exist according to any suitable definition of limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g (x)=x\sin ( \frac {1}{x})   $.

$$\forall x\neq 0 \;\;|x\sin (\frac {1}{x})|\leq |x|$$
thus

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\sin (\frac {1}{x})=0.$$

take $x_n=\frac {1}{\frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi} $
and
$y_n=\frac {1}{\frac {3\pi}{2}+2n\pi} $
we have

$g (x_n)\to 0^+$ and $f (x_n)\to+\infty $
$g (y_n)\to 0^-$ and $f (y_n)\to-\infty $

we conclude that 
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x) $$
doesn't exist.

Comment: $g(\frac{1}{n\pi}) = +\infty$ iff $n$ is an integer, taking the limit as $n$ approaches infinity does not make it an integer, right?

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury yes of course.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I think the second limit is also infinity . $\lim_{n\to+\infty}g (\frac {1}{\frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi})= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi =  \infty$

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, i modified. Thanks.

Comment: My problem is the value of $\frac {1}{x\sin (\frac {1}{x})}$ doesn't exist on $0$ neighborhood . Therefore we can't say limit is $\pm \infty$ .

Comment: I said : it doesn't exist  because it oscillates between $+\infty $ and $-\infty$.